# Perform Calculation in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i would like to perform a calculation for this DataFrame `['REGIS_HOUR']`

[image]

If `['REGIS_HOUR']` is more than 12, then `['REGIS_HOUR']-12`
but it doesn't work. I did convert to int using `astype('int')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['REGIS_HOUR'] = np.where(df['REGIS_HOUR'] > 12, df['REGIS_HOUR'] -12, df['REGIS_HOUR'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['REGIS_HOUR'] = df['REGIS_HOUR'] % 12
```